# Using SoftLayer REST API in postinstall script without username/apiKey

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Ay one time I was looking at a set to REST API calls that could be used within a PostInstall script without specifying username/apiKey. They where requests to obtain what SoftLayer datacenter the device was in or the VLAN it was on.  Can you point me to these services?

Answer (score 0):

this is the service and the list of its methods:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata

Regards

Comment: Awesome,  Thank you.